# pass a string variable as function argument in python 3 and call it within the function

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to pass a string value as function argument and then call it within the function.

pred_1 and pred_2, pred_1_index and pred_index_2 are external lists which hold int values. I am trying to write a function which takes the list name as an argument and then joing the function argument(pred_1 and pred_2) with '_index' which in turn is stored the value of third elements of pred_1_index and pred_2_index in the variable 'prediction_index' and finally prints it

So ultimate goal of my code is that the function argument name takes place of 'predict' in predict_index.

My code is:

```
predictions = ['pred_1','pred_2']

def count_breakage(predict):
    prediction_index = predict_index[3]
    return print(prediction_index)  

for item in predictions:
    count_breakage(item)
```

But the error i get is:

```
NameError: name 'predict_index' is not defined
```

Any ideas how i can assign the list arguments 'pred_1' and 'pred_2' to the variable 'prediction_index' within the function?

Comment: What is `predict_index` ?

Comment: i should be more clear. so pred_1and pred_2 are external lists and also pred_1_index and pred_2_index which hold int values. I am trying to write a function which takes the list name as an argument and then joing the function argument(pred_1 and pred_2) with '_index' which in turn is stored in the variable 'prediction_index' and finally printed

Comment: `predict` is `'pred_1'` initially; that does not mean `predict_index` is `pred_1_index`.

Comment: exactly. And making predict_index to pred_1_index is my ultimate goal

Comment: We need more code than this to be able to help. In this tiny sample, `predict_index` is not declared _anywhere_

Comment: @JerryM. my goal is to pass the funytion argument name pred_1 inside the function so predict_index becomes pred_1_index

Comment: i have updated the question maybe it helps understanding my goal